# Laravel 5.3 nl2br in email

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to `nl2br` my email in Laravel 5.3.

```
Dear {{ $user->name }} {{ $user->last_name }}, <br><br>

{{ nl2br($request['message']) }}

<br><br>
Regards,<br><br>
```

But the result is:

```
Dear John doe, 

Blablabla<br /> <br /> Blablabla<br /> <br /> blablabla<br /> <br /> blablabla
```

How can I make sure that the `<br />` is realy a breakline?

Comment: That will depend on the rendering capabilities of the e-mail client of the reader. Just send it and see how it looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression `{{ $var }}` is used to encode HTML characters, you should do the following:

```
{!! nl2br(htmlspecialchars($request['message'])) !!}
```

`htmlspecialchars()` : this encodes the special characters to avoid security issues

`nl2br()` : this transforms the new lines to `<br>` tags, but AFTER it has already been secured

`{!! !!}` : this tells Blade to not encode HTML characters when outputting the variable

Note that this is not related to sending emails, it's the same thing for a normal view.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<br>` with `&#13;&#10;`