# Laravel nl2br() with sending emails

Tags: php, email, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3, nl2br

I'm using `Laravel 5.3` and I'm trying to send an email with `nl2br()`. So I'm using the default `email blade file` that's new in `Laravel 5.3` (`vendor/notifications/email.blade.php`)

But it does not show line breaks. Only this:

```
sttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest<br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
```

I've done it like this:

```
<!-- Outro -->
@foreach ($outroLines as $line)
    <p style="{{ $style['``'] }}">
        {{ nl2br($line) }}
    </p>
@endforeach
```

What am I doing wrong?

This:

```
{!! nl2br(htmlspecialchars($line)) !!}
```

is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 nl2br in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220996/laravel-5-3-nl2br-in-email)

Answer (score 4):

Laravel automatically escapes your string by using {{ }}

For laravel 4+ use `{{{ nl2br($line) }}}`

For laravel 5+ use `{!! nl2br($line) !!}`

Correct me if i'm wrong on the versioning.

Comment: This will not work because @Jamie is using the notifications mail channel.

Answer (score 2):

For **Laravel 4** users:

```
{{ nl2br(e($message)) }}
```

`e($x)` is equivalent to `{{{ $x }}}`.

**Laravel 5** users:

```
{!! nl2br(e($message)) !!}
```

`e($x)` is equivalent to `{{ $x }}`.

Comment: Laravel actually removes all the new line symbols before the string would come in `nl2br()`. This is because he is using the notification mail channel.

Comment: This should be top answer, worked for me perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but for everyone with the same problem.
If you are using the notifications mail, new lines will not work ("\n", "\r", "\r\n").

This is because Laravel (for `5.3` and `5.4` I can confirm)  strips these from the lines

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\SimpleMessage.php

```
protected function formatLine($line)
{
    if (is_array($line)) {
        return implode(' ', array_map('trim', $line));
    }

    return trim(implode(' ', array_map('trim', preg_split('/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/', $line))));
}
```

How I solved this is by replacing the new lines with actual html new lines `<br>`.

*There are much better ways of doing this* I'm sure, but the important part is not to overlook the formatLine function.

```
public function toMail($notifiable) {

    //Get your mail data
    $mail = new Email(2);
    $emailLine = $mail->getArray();

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line(str_replace(array("\\r\\n", "\\n", "\\r","\r\n", "\n", "\r"), "<br>", $emailLine))

}
```